# How to use processed DEGs file for UMAP in Seurat?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, seurat

I have a 10-page Excel spreadsheet, each page represents a cell cluster, with the first row being the signature genes for that cell cluster. The data structure is as follows:

```
Gene    p_val   avg_logFC   pct.1   pct.2   p_val_adj
Col15a1 1.4665E-146 1.18233234  0.735   0.217   3.0925E-142
Gsn 4.4013E-143 1.028705212 1   0.91    9.2811E-139
... ... ... ... ... ...
```

My code is as follows:

```
all_data <- lapply(1:10, function(i) {
  data <- read_excel("cells.xlsx", sheet = i)
  colnames(data)[1] <- "Gene"
  data <- data[,c(1,3)]
  row.names(data) <- data$Gene
  return(data)
})

seurat_list <- lapply(all_data, function(data) {
  pbmc <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = as.matrix(data))
  
  pbmc <- NormalizeData(pbmc)
  pbmc <- FindVariableFeatures(pbmc)
  pbmc <- ScaleData(pbmc)
  pbmc <- RunPCA(pbmc, verbose = FALSE)
  pbmc <- RunUMAP(pbmc, reduction = "pca", dims = 1:10)

  return(pbmc)
})
```

However, I encountered the following error:

```
Warning: Data is of class matrix. Coercing to dgCMatrix.
Normalizing layer: counts
Performing log-normalization
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
[----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**************************************************|
Finding variable features for layer counts
Calculating gene variances
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
[----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**************************************************|
Error in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  : 
  'x' incorrect
Warning message:
In matrix(data = as.numeric(x = x), ncol = nc) : NAs introduced by coercion" in as.numeric()
```

Could anyone please help me solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: From a superficial reading it seems `createSeuratObject` expects *counts* (i.e. raw data) whereas you are providing it with log fold changes & *P*-values. Are you sure this is the correct workflow? The specific error is most likely because log fold change can be negative whereas counts cannot, and some subsequent function again takes the log of their input.

Comment: Seurat is almost certainly not the right tool for your data. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

A Seurat object expects counts, not any sort of processed and aggregated data as you have it. There is no meaningful way to convert these files into a Seurat object. You need counts, be it raw counts, or some sort of normalized values to build your object. Please see the Seurat vignettes to get the basics right.